# Am I allowed to play an external song in a Spotify app?

Tags: spotify

Can I play a song that is creative commons and is hosted on my server in a Spotify App?

I want to make playlists that are a mix of Spotify and my own songs in a Spotify app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. See the [Integration Guidelines](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/integration/#non-spotifyaudiocontent).